# MPI C SendRecV matrix multiplication

Tags: c, mpi

I need to send sections of a matrix from the root process to all other processes so they can run calculations on it.  I then need to receive the calculations and aggregate them in the root process.  I would use Scatter, but the Matrices can only exist in the root process (homework stipulation).

I know that MPI_Sendrecv_replace or MPI_Sendrecv will be helpful functions.  However, I need to send a section of the matrix to the other processes, have them compute, and then return.  How am I to use the Sendrecv functions if I need computation to happen in between the sending and receiving.  I am having trouble conceptualizing this.

For example:

```
Process 0 sends to Process 1,2,3
Process 1,2,3 compute sections of matrix
Process 0 receives all of the computations
```

How can this happen if the sendrecv function is all in one?

Furthermore, I think using separate send and receive operations will most certainly cause deadlock (unless I painstakingly manage the calls) since I am going to be doing this on an nxn matrix and it could be large.

How can I use the Sendrecv functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Sendrecv` does not mean that you send something back and forth. `MPI_Sendrecv` rather executes a `send command` at processor A and a `receive command` at processor B. (If you want to send something from A to B)

You need 1 `Sendrecv` for:

```
Process 0 sends to Process 1
```

Then you do the computation and another `Sendrecv` for:

```
Process 0 receives from 1
```